# How can I sort a list that contains complex numbers, using their absolute values?

Tags: python, sorting

Something where you can input an array `[8,2,3+j,1+5j,1]`

where `3+j` is evaluated as `(3^2 + 1^2)^1/2`, or `abs(3+j)`

outputs `[1,2,3+j,1+5j,8]`

Answer (score 2):

Setting `abs` as `key` will do:

```
l = [8,2,3+1j,1+5j,1]

sorted(l, key=abs)
# [1, 2, (3+1j), (1+5j), 8]
```

Note that taking the `abs` of a complex number, will do the same as you've mentioned in the question, i.e. take its [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers):

```
abs(5j + 2)
# 5.385164807134504

np.sqrt(5**2 + 2**2)
# 5.385164807134504
```

Also note that `3+j` is not valid, since python expects `j` to be a variable. To make it a complex literal, the `j` must be after a number, `3 + 1j`. Or you can also do `complex(3, 1)`